# JavaScript, td size always change

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, css-tables

I am writing a simple program that includes table and td's.
In the program when you press `q` the number one appears in a td.
but when it happens the td width suddenly change.
so my question is how to stop it?
here is the code:

```html
    <html>
    <body>
        <table border = "1">
            <tr>
                <td id = "td1"></td>
                <td id = "td2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <style>
            table {
                height: 400px;
                width: 800px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                text-align: center;
                font-size:25px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
                if (e.key == "q") {
                    document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = "1";
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: use width and max-width in css to fix the td size

Answer (score 1):

you can add the following property to your css definition

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <table border = "1">
        <tr>
            <td id = "td1"></td>
            <td id = "td2"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <style>
        table {
            height: 400px;
            width: 800px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            text-align: center;
            font-size:25px;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<head>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
            if (e.key == "q") {
                document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = "1";
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <table border = "1">
        <tr>
            <td id = "td1"></td>
            <td id = "td2"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <style>
        table {
            height: 400px;
            width: 800px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            text-align: center;
            font-size:25px;
        }
        
        td {
          width: 50%;
          }
          
    </style>
</head>

  <body>
      <script>
          document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
              if (e.key == "q") {
                  document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = "1";
              }
          });
      </script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

use this code